# Create a nested dictionary from pd dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following data frame like (in reality with hundreds of rows)

```
    Location Date       Court    Winner 
0   Paris    10/2/2018  Outdoor  Flavio
1   Paris    10/2/2018  Indoor   Luca
2   Paris    10/2/2018  Indoor   Giovanni
3   Paris    10/2/2018  Indoor   Luca
```

What I want to do is to get a nested dictionary that look like that:

```
{ 'Flavio' : { 'Outdoor' : 1 , 'Indoor' : 0 } , 'Luca' : {'Outdoor' : 0 , 'Indoor' : 2} }
```

and so on. So in other words I want to determine the number of times winners won in the Outdoor and in the Indoor court.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a `pivot_table` and `to_dict`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['France','France','France','France'],
                   'Court':['Outdoor','Indoor','Indoor','Indoor'],
                   'Winner':['Flavio','Luca','Giovanni','Luca']})
df = pd.pivot_table(df,values='Location',columns='Winner',index='Court',aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)
a = df.to_dict()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'Flavio': {'Indoor': 0, 'Outdoor': 1}, 'Giovanni': {'Indoor': 1, 'Outdoor': 0}, 'Luca': {'Indoor': 2, 'Outdoor': 0}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = pd.crosstab(df['Court'],df['Winner']).to_dict()
print (d)
{'Flavio': {'Indoor': 0, 'Outdoor': 1},
 'Giovanni': {'Indoor': 1, 'Outdoor': 0}, 
 'Luca': {'Indoor': 2, 'Outdoor': 0}}
```

Comment: Also possible `pd.crosstab(df['Court'], df['Winner']).to_dict()` rather than using `.T`

Comment: You are always first!